# Sentence $\phi_n$ is true in $S$ iff $S$ has at most $n$ elements

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I'm trying to prove this result:

> For any natural number $n \geq 1$ there is a sentence $\phi_n$ such
>   that $\phi_n$ is true in $S$ iff $S$ has at most $n$ elements.

My attempt:

By induction on $n$. Obviously, this is OK for $n=1,2$. Suppose the result holds for all values $\leq n$. We want to proof that $\exists \phi_{n+1}$ such that $\phi_{n+1}$ is true in $S_{n+1}$, i.e. any set with at most $n+1$ elements. IH: $S_n \vDash \phi_n$. Thus, $S_n \cup \{x\} \not \vDash \phi_n$. However, $\{x\} \vDash \phi_1$. Therefore, $S_n \cup \{x\} \vDash \phi_{n} \vee \phi_1$. Define now $\phi_{n+1} = \phi_n \vee \phi_1,$ by induction the result follows.

Is this correct?

Comment: @Crostul: $S$ is any set that one chooses to use as the universe for interpeting first order logic.

Comment: Any non-empty set.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be true to me that "the universe has at most $n+1$ elements" means the same as "the universe has either at most $n$ elements or at most $1$ element".

Comment: (By the way, there are some special-purpose logics where this approach would work. Some [bunched logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunched_logic) have a "$*$" connective such that $\phi*\psi$ is true if the universe splits into separate parts where $\phi$ is true in one of them and $\psi$ is true in the other; so there $\phi_{n+1}\equiv \phi_n*\phi_1$ would indeed work. But that is not at all how the usual $\lor$ connective works!)

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I was afraid of that. I've found an alternative proof, but I was wondering if something like this can work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that doesn't work. Defining, for example, $\phi_3$ to be $\phi_2\lor\phi_1$ amounts to saying

> The universe has at most 3 elements if it either has 1 or 2 elements or has 1 element.

which is obviously not the case.

The standard solution would be something like
$$ \phi_n \equiv \forall x_0\forall x_1\cdots \forall x_n(
x_0=x_1 \lor x_0=x_2 \lor x_0=x_3 \lor \cdots \lor x_0=x_n \lor x_1=x_2 \lor \cdots ) $$
which intuitively says "if you pick $n+1$ things some of them will be the same" or "you can't pick $n+1$ things that are all different".

Comment: +1, same solution as I have! Thanks for the clarification!